# Getting position in array within a multi dimentional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array like this ;

```
 A:    Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => name1 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => name2 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => name3 ) 
        )
```

And I have a array like this;

```
 B:    Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => name2 )
        )
```

How to get the position of `$b` in `$a`? I want an output like **0,1,2**...

Else if **B = `name2`** can I get the position from **A** as **0,1,2**... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the
>   first corresponding key if successful

```
<?php

$a= [
        ['id'   =>  1, 'name'   =>  'name1'],
        ['id'   =>  2, 'name'   =>  'name2'],
        ['id'   =>  3, 'name'   =>  'name3'],
       ];

$b= ['id'   =>  2, 'name'   =>  'name2'];

$index = array_search($b, $a);

echo $index;      

?>
```

Output: 1

Since your needle position is in index 1 of array $a, you will get 1.